# Как воздействовать на svg в css, подключив его отдельным файлом?

Tags: css, svg, svg-спрайт

Я хочу использовать псевдоклассы CSS (`:hover`, `:active`), подключив svg отдельным файлом воздействовать на него в css.

Я сделал вот так,
svg-файл:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="./journey-svg.css"?>
<svg 
    version="1.1"
    baseProfile="full"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
    width="800"
    height="800"
    viewBox="0 0 800 800"
> 

    <defs>
        <style>
        
            #journey {
                fill: var(--journey, black);
            }

        </style>
    </defs>

    <path id="journey" alignment-baseline="" d="M227.699 1.199H25.301c-13.234 0-24 10.766-24 24v197.602c0 13.23 10.766 24 24 24h202.398c13.235 0 24-10.77 24-24V25.199c0-13.234-10.765-24-24-24zm0 24l.008 104.98-40.543-38.078c-2.836-2.66-6.468-4.125-10.226-4.125-4.571 0-8.848 2.145-11.739 5.883l-47.73 61.805c-1.547 2.004-4.027 3.199-6.637 3.199-1.781 0-3.461-.539-4.863-1.566l-31.016-22.653c-3.09-2.254-7.093-3.5-11.269-3.5-4.758 0-9.203 1.551-12.52 4.367l-25.863 21.934V25.199h202.398zm0 0M93.301 96.398c13.676 0 24.801-11.125 24.801-24.801 0-13.671-11.125-24.796-24.801-24.796-13.676 0-24.801 11.125-24.801 24.796 0 13.676 11.125 24.801 24.801 24.801zm0 0" />
</svg>
```

Но я не могу достучаться туда CSS'ом, он не видит CSS-переменную, пример:

```html
<style>
    :root {
        --journey: red;
    }
</style>

<object type="image/svg+xml" data="./images/journey-svg/journey-svg.svg" width="400" height="400"> </object>
```

Но если бы я просто вставил svg прямо в файл, то всё будет работать:

```css
:root {
  --journey: red;
}

#journey-svg {
  --size: 100px;
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
}

#journey-svg:hover {
  --journey: green;
}

#journey-svg:active {
  --journey: orange;
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="./journey-svg.css"?>
<svg 
    version="1.1"
    baseProfile="full"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
  width="800"
    height="800"
    viewBox="0 0 250 250"
  id="journey-svg"
> 

    <defs>
        <style>
        
            #journey {
                fill: var(--journey, black);
        transition: fill 0.2s ease-in-out;
            }

        </style>
    </defs>

    <path id="journey" alignment-baseline="" d="M227.699 1.199H25.301c-13.234 0-24 10.766-24 24v197.602c0 13.23 10.766 24 24 24h202.398c13.235 0 24-10.77 24-24V25.199c0-13.234-10.765-24-24-24zm0 24l.008 104.98-40.543-38.078c-2.836-2.66-6.468-4.125-10.226-4.125-4.571 0-8.848 2.145-11.739 5.883l-47.73 61.805c-1.547 2.004-4.027 3.199-6.637 3.199-1.781 0-3.461-.539-4.863-1.566l-31.016-22.653c-3.09-2.254-7.093-3.5-11.269-3.5-4.758 0-9.203 1.551-12.52 4.367l-25.863 21.934V25.199h202.398zm0 0M93.301 96.398c13.676 0 24.801-11.125 24.801-24.801 0-13.671-11.125-24.796-24.801-24.796-13.676 0-24.801 11.125-24.801 24.796 0 13.676 11.125 24.801 24.801 24.801zm0 0" />
</svg>
```

Comment: svg работает в своей области видимости. Можете заинлайнить svg, тогда достучаться получится.

Comment: @nazarpunk что значит заинлайнить? Покажите ответом, если не сложно

Comment: это значит всключить svg напрямую в html, а не файлом.

Comment: @nazarpunk так я так и сделал, показал пример, но мне так не очень нравится

Comment: @МихаилКамахин Добавлен второй [ответ с переменными](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1377720/28748)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Добавление SVG иконок с помощью спрайта

Если иконок немного, то с помощью `<symbol>` можно вручную сделать спрайт, не используя вебпак и другие подобные программы. Дополнительная польза,-  написав один раз спрайт вручную, вы всегда будете знать, как настроить вебпак, чтобы получить аналогичный результат.

---

***Формируем спрайт из SVG иконок***

Копируете в svg файл, который планируете использовать, как спрайт, код иконок и оборачиваете его тегом `<symbol>` присвоив ему ID.

```
<symbol id="phone" viewBox="0 0 48 48">
    <path fill="#009688"  d="M39.1,7l-3.7,0C22.2,7.2..... />
</symbol>
```

Повторяете это для всех иконок, присваивая уникальные ID

Готовый файл нужно сохранить с раcширением  *.svg и разместить его на сервере.

Ниже спрайт с двумя иконками: `id="headphones"` и `id="phone" viewBox="0 0 48 48"`

`viewBox` добавлен, чтобы сделать иконки одинакового размера.

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="0" height="0" viewBox="0 0 100 500" style="border:1px solid">
<symbol id="headphones">
   <path  d="M89 31.3c-1.5-.1-3 .3-4.1 1a38 38 0 0 0-27-25.6c-13-3-26.4 2-35 12a40 40 0 0 0-7.6 13.8 7 7 0 0 0-10.8 6l2 30.2c.4 7.3 10.8 8.7 13.3 1.9-6.4-8.7-8.6-22.4-1.5-31.3v-.1c2-12.6 10.8-24 23.2-27.7A31.3 31.3 0 0 1 75 23c3.4 4.5 5.7 9.7 6.7 15.2v.9c7.3 8.7 5 23-1.4 31.5 2.5 6.8 12.8 5.3 13.3-1.9l2-30.1c.2-3.8-2.7-7.1-6.5-7.3" />
  <path d="M81.5 42.2c-3-5-8.7-7.7-14.5-7.7h-.2c-9.5.7-13 6.2-15.8 12.3l-1 2-.8-2c-2.8-6-7-12.3-16.7-12.3h-.3c-6.3.4-11.8 3.8-14.5 9.7-3 6.5-2 14.4 1 20.8 3.2 6.6 9.1 11.5 14.6 16.2C38.8 86 44.6 90 50.2 94.5c8.7-7.8 18.8-13.9 26.5-22.7 3.6-4 6.1-8.7 7-14.1.8-5.2.6-10.9-2.2-15.5z" />
</symbol>
   <symbol id="phone" viewBox="0 0 48 48">
    <path fill="#009688"  d="M39.1,7l-3.7,0C22.2,7.2,7.1,24.1,7,35.4l0,3.7c0,1,0.8,1.9,1.9,1.9l7.5-0.1c1,0,1.9-0.9,1.9-1.9l0.2-8.2 l-4.7-4c0-2.6,10.5-13.1,13.2-13.2l4.3,4.7l7.9-0.2c1,0,1.9-0.9,1.9-1.9L41,8.9C41,7.8,40.2,7,39.1,7z"  />
   </symbol>
</svg>
```

Ничего не выводится, так как `<symbol>` скрывает содержимое до вызова иконки по ID с  помощью `<use>`

---

Перед этим необходимо добавить спрайт в HTML с помощью `<object>`

---

Следующий шаг:

### Вызов иконки по ID с  помощью `<use>`

```
 <svg width="100">
    <use id="u1"  xlink:href="#headphones" />
</svg>
```

Ниже полный код вызова и стилизации иконок:

```css
svg {
display:block;
}
 #u1,#u2,#u3,#u4 {
 transition:all 0.5s; 
 fill:black;
 }
 #u1:hover {
 fill:red;
 }
 
 #u2:hover {
 fill:dodgerblue;
 } 

  
  #u3:hover {
 fill: yellowgreen;
 } 
 
 #u4:hover {
 fill: purple;
 }
```

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="0" height="0" viewBox="0 0 100 500" style="border:1px solid">
<symbol id="headphones">
   <path  d="M89 31.3c-1.5-.1-3 .3-4.1 1a38 38 0 0 0-27-25.6c-13-3-26.4 2-35 12a40 40 0 0 0-7.6 13.8 7 7 0 0 0-10.8 6l2 30.2c.4 7.3 10.8 8.7 13.3 1.9-6.4-8.7-8.6-22.4-1.5-31.3v-.1c2-12.6 10.8-24 23.2-27.7A31.3 31.3 0 0 1 75 23c3.4 4.5 5.7 9.7 6.7 15.2v.9c7.3 8.7 5 23-1.4 31.5 2.5 6.8 12.8 5.3 13.3-1.9l2-30.1c.2-3.8-2.7-7.1-6.5-7.3" />
  <path d="M81.5 42.2c-3-5-8.7-7.7-14.5-7.7h-.2c-9.5.7-13 6.2-15.8 12.3l-1 2-.8-2c-2.8-6-7-12.3-16.7-12.3h-.3c-6.3.4-11.8 3.8-14.5 9.7-3 6.5-2 14.4 1 20.8 3.2 6.6 9.1 11.5 14.6 16.2C38.8 86 44.6 90 50.2 94.5c8.7-7.8 18.8-13.9 26.5-22.7 3.6-4 6.1-8.7 7-14.1.8-5.2.6-10.9-2.2-15.5z" />
</symbol>
   <symbol id="phone" viewBox="0 0 48 48">
    <path fill="#009688"  d="M39.1,7l-3.7,0C22.2,7.2,7.1,24.1,7,35.4l0,3.7c0,1,0.8,1.9,1.9,1.9l7.5-0.1c1,0,1.9-0.9,1.9-1.9l0.2-8.2 l-4.7-4c0-2.6,10.5-13.1,13.2-13.2l4.3,4.7l7.9-0.2c1,0,1.9-0.9,1.9-1.9L41,8.9C41,7.8,40.2,7,39.1,7z"/  />
   </symbol>
</svg>
  <svg width="100">
    <use id="u1"  xlink:href="#headphones" />
</svg>
<svg width="100">   
     <use id="u2"  xlink:href="#headphones"/>
 </svg> 
 <svg width="100" height="100"> 
     <use id="u3"  xlink:href="#phone"   />
 </svg>  
 
 <svg width="100" height="100"> 
     <use id="u4"  xlink:href="#phone"  />
 </svg>
```

Получаем результат: иконка с наушниками меняет цвет при `:hover`, а телефонная трубка не реагирует.

Это происходит из-за того, что в иконке с наушниками ***нет атрибутов представления***, а у иконки телефонной трубки есть - `fill="#009688"` и вес  стиля представления SVG, больше, чем стиль внешней таблицы CSS.

Каждый раз удалять стили представления из SVG довольно накладно. Но есть выход,- применить `Computed` стили, которые имеют наивысший приоритет.

### Использование переменных для стилизации

В нашем случае будут использоваться переменные во внешнем CSS

```
#u1:hover {
 --primary-color: red;
 --second-color: purple;
 }
```

То есть видим, что можно менять несколько цветов одновременно.
Это даёт возможность для стилизации **многоцветных иконок**.

---

И внутри  SVG:

```
style="fill: var(--second-color, grey)
```

```css
svg {
display:inline;
}
 #u1,#u2 {
 transition:all 0.5s; 
 fill:black;
 }
 #u1:hover {
 --primary-color: red;
 --second-color: purple;
 }
 
 #u2:hover {
 --primary-color: red;
 --second-color: dodgerblue;
 } 

  
  #u3:hover {
 --primary-color: yellowgreen;
 } 
 
 #u4:hover {
 --primary-color: purple;
 }
```

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="0" height="0" viewBox="0 0 100 500" style="border:1px solid">
<symbol id="headphones">
   <path fill="grey" d="M89 31.3c-1.5-.1-3 .3-4.1 1a38 38 0 0 0-27-25.6c-13-3-26.4 2-35 12a40 40 0 0 0-7.6 13.8 7 7 0 0 0-10.8 6l2 30.2c.4 7.3 10.8 8.7 13.3 1.9-6.4-8.7-8.6-22.4-1.5-31.3v-.1c2-12.6 10.8-24 23.2-27.7A31.3 31.3 0 0 1 75 23c3.4 4.5 5.7 9.7 6.7 15.2v.9c7.3 8.7 5 23-1.4 31.5 2.5 6.8 12.8 5.3 13.3-1.9l2-30.1c.2-3.8-2.7-7.1-6.5-7.3" style="fill: var(--second-color, grey)"/>
  <path fill="grey" d="M81.5 42.2c-3-5-8.7-7.7-14.5-7.7h-.2c-9.5.7-13 6.2-15.8 12.3l-1 2-.8-2c-2.8-6-7-12.3-16.7-12.3h-.3c-6.3.4-11.8 3.8-14.5 9.7-3 6.5-2 14.4 1 20.8 3.2 6.6 9.1 11.5 14.6 16.2C38.8 86 44.6 90 50.2 94.5c8.7-7.8 18.8-13.9 26.5-22.7 3.6-4 6.1-8.7 7-14.1.8-5.2.6-10.9-2.2-15.5z" style="fill: var(--primary-color, grey)"/>
</symbol>
   <symbol id="phone" viewBox="0 0 48 48">
    <path id="pathPhone"  d="M39.1,7l-3.7,0C22.2,7.2,7.1,24.1,7,35.4l0,3.7c0,1,0.8,1.9,1.9,1.9l7.5-0.1c1,0,1.9-0.9,1.9-1.9l0.2-8.2 l-4.7-4c0-2.6,10.5-13.1,13.2-13.2l4.3,4.7l7.9-0.2c1,0,1.9-0.9,1.9-1.9L41,8.9C41,7.8,40.2,7,39.1,7z"/ fill="#009688" style="fill: var(--primary-color, #009688)"/>
   </symbol>
</svg>
  <svg width="100">
    <use id="u1"  xlink:href="#headphones" />
</svg>
<svg width="100">   
     <use id="u2"  xlink:href="#headphones"/>
 </svg> 
 <svg width="100" height="100"> 
     <use id="u3"  xlink:href="#phone"   />
 </svg>  
 
 <svg width="100" height="100"> 
     <use id="u4"  xlink:href="#phone"  />
 </svg>
```

Comment: Я и не знал, что SVG можно в спрайты объединять... Сейчас большинство сайтов http2 правда используют, разницы между отдачей десятка отдельных svg и одного спрайта нет совсем, но тем не менее, применение этому точно найду.

Comment: Классно, благодарю за ответ!

Answer (score 3):

Если не хочется добавлять SVG  инлайн в HTML, то можно добавить файл SVG с помощью `<object>` Но в этом случае до svg достучаться стилями напрямую не удастся, так как это изолированный объект.

Поэтому стили заранее помещаем в svg файл и загружаем его на сервер

Вот отдельный SVG файл c :hover стилем для path

```html
<svg 
    version="1.1"
    baseProfile="full"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
    width="800"
    height="800"
    viewBox="0 0 800 800"
> 

    <defs>
        <style>
        
      #journey {
          fill: black);
       }
            #journey:hover{
            fill:orange;
            }
        </style>
    </defs>

    <path id="journey" alignment-baseline="" d="M227.699 1.199H25.301c-13.234 0-24 10.766-24 24v197.602c0 13.23 10.766 24 24 24h202.398c13.235 0 24-10.77 24-24V25.199c0-13.234-10.765-24-24-24zm0 24l.008 104.98-40.543-38.078c-2.836-2.66-6.468-4.125-10.226-4.125-4.571 0-8.848 2.145-11.739 5.883l-47.73 61.805c-1.547 2.004-4.027 3.199-6.637 3.199-1.781 0-3.461-.539-4.863-1.566l-31.016-22.653c-3.09-2.254-7.093-3.5-11.269-3.5-4.758 0-9.203 1.551-12.52 4.367l-25.863 21.934V25.199h202.398zm0 0M93.301 96.398c13.676 0 24.801-11.125 24.801-24.801 0-13.671-11.125-24.796-24.801-24.796-13.676 0-24.801 11.125-24.801 24.796 0 13.676 11.125 24.801 24.801 24.801zm0 0" />
</svg>
```

А теперь вызываем svg с сервера

```html
<object  type="image/svg+xml" data="https://svg-art.ru/files/journey-svg.svg" width="400" height="400"></object>
```

*Вариант с помощью спрайта (symbol)*

Чтобы иметь возможность изменять стили из внешнего CSS, нужно удалить все стили представления svg (fill, stroke,opacity) обернуть path `<symbol>` добавить к нему`id="journey"`

Загрузить svg файл в HTML

```
<object  type="image/svg+xml" data="https://svg-art.ru/files/journey-svg.svg" width="400" height="400"></object>
```

и далее вызывать сколько угодно раз с помощью `<use>`

`<use xlink:href="#journey" />`

На SO есть целый раздел [svg-sprite](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svg-%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82) можно посмотреть различные нюансы, решения

Comment: Понял, короче вебпаком легче это делать или на JS написать какую-то штуку

Comment: А если SVG прописать `fill="currentColor"`, а для `<object...` прописать стили `object:hover {color: red;}`, такой вариант будет работать? Лень в IDE лезть тестировать...

Comment: @Pilaton нет, так не получится. Так как  `<object>` это изолированный объект, просто стилями извне сделать ничего не удастся. Можно лишь, как картинку css фильтрами перекрашивать.

Comment: @Pilaton посмотри новый ответ. Мне показалось, что ты заинтересовался немного SVG/  Кстати, какую IDE ты используешь?

Comment: @Alexandr_TT Да, глянул, в блокнот себе скопипастил. IDE Vscode и Webstorm

Answer (score 0):

Можете вставить `svg` напрямую в `html`. Тогда браузер разрешит доступ к нему из внешних стилей.

```css
svg {
  width: 30px;
}

svg:hover {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 250 250">
  <path d="M227.7 1.2H25.3a24 24 0 0 0-24 24v197.6a24 24 0 0 0 24 24h202.4a24 24 0 0 0 24-24V25.2a24 24 0 0 0-24-24zm0 24v105L187.2 92a14.8 14.8 0 0 0-22 1.8l-47.7 61.8a8.4 8.4 0 0 1-11.5 1.6l-31-22.7a19.7 19.7 0 0 0-11.3-3.5c-4.8 0-9.2 1.6-12.5 4.4l-25.9 22V25.1h202.4zM93.3 96.4a24.8 24.8 0 1 0 0-49.7 24.8 24.8 0 0 0 0 49.7zm0 0" />
</svg>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 250 250">
  <path d="M227.7 1.2H25.3a24 24 0 0 0-24 24v197.6a24 24 0 0 0 24 24h202.4a24 24 0 0 0 24-24V25.2a24 24 0 0 0-24-24zm0 24v105L187.2 92a14.8 14.8 0 0 0-22 1.8l-47.7 61.8a8.4 8.4 0 0 1-11.5 1.6l-31-22.7a19.7 19.7 0 0 0-11.3-3.5c-4.8 0-9.2 1.6-12.5 4.4l-25.9 22V25.1h202.4zM93.3 96.4a24.8 24.8 0 1 0 0-49.7 24.8 24.8 0 0 0 0 49.7zm0 0" />
</svg>
```